# Auto-complete / Auto-suggest for suburb (esp. Australia)

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

Is there any preferred AJAX auto-suggest API out there which has **a database of a list of suburbs (esp. Australia)** as the user types into the textbox?

Comment: @Wojitku: I think I should rephrase my question! I wanted to know if there area any API out there which has a complete database of Australian suburbs so I can use AJAX autocomplete alongside with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here:
- http://www.geonames.org/export/ajax-postalcode-autocomplete.html
- http://www.geonames.org/export/free-geocoding.html
- http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/

Answer (score -2):

Read about **AJAX**, **JavaScript**, XML etc. first... Then you can check out (for example) [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) and it's [**Autocomplete** plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).