# api for ajax autocomplete for australian suburb

Tags: api, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking at

[www.property.com.au](http://www.property.com.au)

and

[www.suburbview.com](http://www.suburbview.com)

They have a search box that when you type in the letters of a suburb, it begins to suggest suburbs names you are looking for.

Any ideas on how it is implemented?

I believe it's using the Google Maps API Ajax calls, but which ones specifically, I would like to discover. Any ideas?

Comment: You should check out this previous post where the OP solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172355/auto-complete-auto-suggest-for-suburb-esp-australia

Answer (score 2):

It's probably using the Australia Post API.  http://auspost.com.au/devcentre/resources.html

I actually found your question while searching for additional information for implementing such a feature.  I would recommend checking out the AJAX calls in firebug if you want to be sure.

**Edit:**

After some quick checking, it looks like it's posting the query to some file located on their server.  If you're looking for Australian Suburb to Postcode lookups definitely check out that link I posted.  It has all Australia Post's developers' resources, and also allows you to register an API key with ease.

Comment: I tried to register for the API but when they send an email, it comes like Your API key is: ${formData.get("apiKey").get(0)}. Somehow they are not parsing the API key. I wonder now that i'm registered is there any other place that I can get the API key, or if it's not on the email, it isn't anywhere! Any takers?